# Forge library not detected

Tags: shared-libraries, minecraft-forge

I'm a Java novice and I wanted to train by modding on minecraft. I followed tutos on youtube (it was old tutos because I couldn't find a new one) and I installed MCP, I run some commands (some of them get me to an error) and when I finally started ta code I notice that all the method and things in relation with the forge library were in red. I couldn't use any of the resources and it told me that it cannot resolve the symbol of the word that were a problem on it. So please did anyone have a solution I searched alot on internet but all I found its old tutos that wasn't working.
PS:I'm French sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, navigate to the directory where you had extracted the files from the MDK Zip. Open command line in this folder and type-

For Windows

```
gradlew eclipse
```

For Mac/Linux

```
./gradlew eclipse
```

Then, re-import your project from your IDE.